# Raphael Map coords

Tags: dictionary, raphael, coords

can someone tell me how can I change the coords from this script ( I use it in dreamweaver ): http://jsfiddle.net/EVFEC/ . I made a SVG map with Adobe illustrator, I tried to copy the now coords in this script but it doesn't work... Why?

Comment: You have to be a bit more specific, what is your concrete problem? I can select countries and when I click on the link text it alerts the selected ones. So what doesn't work?

Comment: My problem is that I want to make my own map. I use Adobe illustrator or Inkscape, when I put my coords from my own SVG map it doesn't work... why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standalone vector graphics editors such as InkScape will flip the Y axis, as their coordinate system differs.

A [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/170049) has been filed to the InkScape issue tracking forum on launchpad (though it is debatable whether it should be considered a bug), and the [issue](http://inkscape.13.n6.nabble.com/coordinate-system-flip-for-0-45-td2802529.html) is [well known](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=12048).

Several approaches may be used to solve this (all addressing the use of InkScape):

- Specify the width and height of and SVG document explicitly prior to importing into InkScape, as suggested [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/14364)
- Rewrite all absolute coordinate values as relative, as offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737394/inkscape-moveto-coords-way-off-in-raphael)
- Wait for the [feature request](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105590/how-can-i-set-top-left-corner-to-have-0-0-coordinates-in-inkscape) to be fulfilled. Someone [suggested at AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105590/how-can-i-set-top-left-corner-to-have-0-0-coordinates-in-inkscape) that it's targeted for version 0.49, but the [roadmap](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Roadmap#Inkscape_0.49) currently shows no real evidence to support that claim.
- Compensate for the irregularity by subtracting the InkScape document height from the Y axis values on the transformation matrix.

Comment: I wnat to draw this map http://www.vectortemplates.com/raster/maps-world-map-03.png   in InkScape at this dimension ( 7408x4176 ) what exactly I need please help me..