# How do prevent Inkscape from adding transforms when exporting SVGs?

Tags: svg, icons, transform, inkscape

I'm working with Inkscape on some SVG icons, and every time I create a new icon, Inkscape applies `transform=translate(...)` on the image. This moves the image from its' X=0,Y=0 to some awkward coordinates.

I found an answer, on how to eliminate the transforms, manually, on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329125/removing-transforms-in-svg-files), but I need to be able to prevent Inkscape from doing this, as it is kind of a productivity hit for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, the `"transform=translate"` part was added to the default layer because I changed the page size **after** creating the document. This is how Inkscape resolved the size change.

After eliminating the translation (as described in the thread referenced in the question), it did not appear again for new layers or objects.