# Why won't this SVG rasterize fine with my code?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, svg, skiasharp

I'm getting the svg string from [this library](https://github.com/nimiq/iqons), and I wanted to rasterize it on both Android and iOS with SkiaSharp:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 160 160" width="160" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/2000/xlink">
<defs>
    <clipPath id="hexagon-clip-3602224084" transform="scale(0.5) translate(0, 16)">
        <path d="M251.6 17.34l63.53 110.03c5.72 9.9 5.72 22.1 0 32L251.6 269.4c-5.7 9.9-16.27 16-27.7 16H96.83c-11.43 0-22-6.1-27.7-16L5.6 159.37c-5.7-9.9-5.7-22.1 0-32L69.14 17.34c5.72-9.9 16.28-16 27.7-16H223.9c11.43 0 22 6.1 27.7 16z" />
    </clipPath>
</defs>
<path fill="white" stroke="#bbbbbb" transform="translate(0, 8) scale(0.5)" d="M251.6 17.34l63.53 110.03c5.72 9.9 5.72 22.1 0 32L251.6 269.4c-5.7 9.9-16.27 16-27.7 16H96.83c-11.43 0-22-6.1-27.7-16L5.6 159.37c-5.7-9.9-5.7-22.1 0-32L69.14 17.34c5.72-9.9 16.28-16 27.7-16H223.9c11.43 0 22 6.1 27.7 16z" />
<g transform="scale(0.9) translate(9, 8)">
    <g clip-path="url(#hexagon-clip-3602224084)">
        <g color="#3949ab" fill="#fb8c00">
            <rect fill="#795548" x="0" y="0" width="160" height="160">
            </rect>
            <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="40" fill="#3949ab">
            </circle>
            <g opacity=".1" fill="#010101">
                <path d="M119.21,80a39.46,39.46,0,0,1-67.13,28.13c10.36,2.33,36,3,49.82-14.28,10.39-12.47,8.31-33.23,4.16-43.26A39.35,39.35,0,0,1,119.21,80Z" />
            </g>
            <path d="M78.1 20.6C59.9 21.7 45.6 26.4 46 31.1s15.5 7.7 33.7 6.6 32.5-5.8 32.1-10.5-15.6-7.7-33.7-6.6zm1.3 14.5c-16.3.9-29.8-1.1-30.1-4.6s12.6-7.1 29-8.1 29.8 1.1 30.1 4.6-12.6 7.1-29 8.1z" opacity=".1" />
            <path d="M78.1 19.6C59.9 20.7 45.6 25.4 46 30.1s15.5 7.7 33.7 6.6 32.5-5.8 32.1-10.5-15.6-7.7-33.7-6.6zm1.3 14.5c-16.3.9-29.8-1.1-30.1-4.6s12.6-7.1 29-8.1 29.8 1.1 30.1 4.6-12.6 7.1-29 8.1z" fill="#fff800" />
            <path d="M29.958 70.973s6.103-5.042 10.083 2.034c3.98 7.076-.973 12.118-.973 12.118s11.057 15.302 19.106 16.187c0 0 3.361-4.865 10.26-1.504 6.9 3.361 3.804 9.464 3.804 9.464s-2.035 4.07-9.022 4.07c-6.988 0-24.148-13.092-30.163-25.121-6.014-12.03-4.068-15.214-3.095-17.248z" stroke-width=".885" />
            <path d="M29.958 70.973s6.103-5.042 10.083 2.034c3.98 7.076-.973 12.118-.973 12.118s11.057 15.302 19.106 16.187c0 0 3.361-4.865 10.26-1.504 6.9 3.361 3.804 9.464 3.804 9.464-4.334-7.518-7.873-6.633-15.214-6.191-12.118-3.184-21.582-14.418-20.079-16.806 0 .088 5.307-14.595-6.987-15.302z" opacity=".18" fill="#010101" stroke-width=".885" />
            <path d="M26.7 55.6c-4.2 2.2-8.8 8.3-9.7 13" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
            <path d="M30 59.2c-3.4 1.8-7.2 6.8-7.9 10.7" opacity=".6" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
            <path d="M94 85s4.8-2 8.2 0c.8.4.7 1.1 0 2 0 0-3.4 4-4.1 4s-4.8-4-4.8-4c-.6-1-.3-1.7.7-2z" fill="#3a3a3a" />
            <path d="M99.3 84.1c1 .2 2 .4 3 .9.8.4.7 1.1 0 2-1.2 1.5-2.6 2.9-4.1 4 1.9-3.2 2.6-6.3 1.1-6.9z" opacity=".2" />
            <path d="M96 100c1.6.2 2-5.8 2-9M88 95.5s7.5 11 18 0" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
            <path d="M79 82s0-12 6-12 6 11.6 6 11.6S86 70 79 82zM102 82s0-12 6-12 6 11.6 6 11.6-5-11.6-12 .4z" fill="#010101" opacity=".6" />
            <path d="M96 86s4-1 6 0h-6z" opacity=".3" fill="#fff" />
            <path d="M93 90c-9.9-3.8-20.4-6.2-31-7M92.6 91.3c-12-2.8-27.7-1.2-27.7-1.2M92.5 93.2c-12.3-1-27.6 5-27.6 5M101 90c8.5-3.8 17.7-6.2 27-7M101.3 91.3c10.5-2.8 24.1-1.2 24.1-1.2M101.4 93.2c10.7-1 24 5 24 5" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
            <path d="M46.4 101.1s-1.3 1.9-1.1 5.9c.7 9.7-2.1 19.5 3.5 26.4 5.6 7 16.7 11.8 22.9 8.4s5.6-15.3-1.4-20.2c-1.7-1.4-3.2-2.9-4.4-4.7-7.9-3.2-14.6-8.1-19.5-15.8z" fill="#99671d" />
            <path d="M46.4 101.1s-1.3 1.9-1.1 5.9c.7 9.7-2.1 19.5 3.5 26.4 12.2 12.9 22.9 8.4 22.9 8.4-10.1 1.1-21.6-35.8-21.6-35.8-1.4-1.5-2.6-3.1-3.7-4.9z" fill="#6d4716" />
            <path d="M54.8 115.4c-4 0-7.3-3.3-7.3-7.3.1-1.3.5-2.7 1.1-3.8.1-.2 7.1 8.1 10.8 9.5 0-.1-1.3 1.2-4.6 1.6z" fill="#fff" />
            <path d="M58.8 113.3c-.8.3-1.7.5-2.6.6-3.4-.1-6-2.9-5.9-6.3 0-.6.1-1.2.2-1.8 0 .2 4.6 6.2 8.3 7.5z" opacity=".2" />
            <path d="M94 124.5s-2.8 5.5-5.5 7.5c-1.2.8-2.3 1.8-3.4 2.7v4.4c0 .4 10.2-3 8.9-14.6z" fill="#6d4716" />
            <path d="M94.6 124.5s-5.4-1.4-8.9 2c-3.4 3.4-3.4 8.2-1.4 8.2s2.2.7 10.3-10.2z" fill="#fff" />
            <path d="M120.5 108.8s-4.8-8.2-19.1-.7c-14.3 7.5-2.7 23.2-15.7 30.7 0 0 3.7 3.64 8.39-5.85 4.644-9.396 4.61-24.75 26.41-24.15z" fill="#99671d" />
            <path d="M85.8 138.8s6.1 2.7 10.2-10.9 8.9-21.8 20.4-21.1c1.6 0 3.2.6 4.4 1.7 5.6 5 1.3 19.6-4.4 24.2-6.8 5.4-21.8 10.9-27.9 8.9s-2.7-2.8-2.7-2.8z" fill="#444" />
            <path d="M84.8 119.2l1 7.4c1.9-1.4 3.6-2.3 5-2.3l-.6-6.2c-1.8.5-3.6.8-5.4 1.1z" fill="#ffc866" />
            <path d="M119.2 112.6h-11.6c-.3 0-.5-.2-.5-.5v-.1c0-.3.2-.5.5-.5h11.6c.3 0 .5.2.5.5v.1c0 .3-.2.5-.5.5zM120.3 115.8h-14.7c-.3 0-.5-.2-.5-.5v-.1c0-.3.2-.5.5-.5h14.7c.3 0 .5.2.5.5v.1c0 .3-.3.5-.5.5zM120.3 118.9h-17.9c-.3 0-.5-.2-.5-.5v-.1c0-.3.2-.5.5-.5h17.9c.3 0 .5.2.5.5v.1c0 .3-.3.5-.5.5zM119.2 122.1h-17.9c-.3 0-.5-.2-.5-.5v-.1c0-.3.2-.5.5-.5h17.9c.3 0 .5.2.5.5v.1c0 .2-.2.5-.5.5zM118.1 125.2h-17.9c-.3 0-.5-.2-.5-.5v-.1c0-.3.2-.5.5-.5h17.9c.3 0 .5.2.5.5v.1c0 .3-.2.5-.5.5zM116.1 128.4H98.2c-.3 0-.5-.2-.5-.5s.2-.5.5-.5h17.9c.3 0 .5.2.5.5 0 .2-.3.5-.5.5zM114 131.5H98.2c-.3 0-.5-.2-.5-.5s.2-.5.5-.5H114c.3 0 .5.2.5.5v.1c0 .2-.3.4-.5.4zM109.8 134.7H96.1c-.3 0-.5-.2-.5-.5v-.1c0-.3.2-.5.5-.5h13.7c.3 0 .5.2.5.5v.1c0 .2-.3.5-.5.5zM104.5 137.8H95c-.3 0-.5-.2-.5-.5v-.1c0-.3.2-.5.5-.5h9.5c.3 0 .5.2.5.5v.1c0 .3-.2.5-.5.5z" />
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

This is how I'm currently doing it:

```
var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(svgStoredAsString);
using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
{
    var svg = new SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg.SKSvg();
    svg.Load(inputStream);
    using (var bitmap = new SKBitmap(100, 100))
    using (var canvas = new SKCanvas(bitmap))
    {
        canvas.Scale(100 / svg.CanvasSize.Width, 100 / svg.CanvasSize.Height);
        canvas.DrawPicture(svg.Picture);
        canvas.Flush();
        canvas.Save();

        using (var file = File.OpenWrite(path))
        using (var outputStream = new SKManagedWStream(file))
        {
            bitmap.Encode(outputStream, SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 100);
        }
    }
}

((Image)image).Source = ImageSource.FromFile(path);
```

The svg shows just fine on the browser and even opens on Illustrator:

[image]

This is what I'm getting instead when rasterizing with my code:

[image]

Comment: Just an FYI, I tried that SVG in a few of SVG libraries on iOS and Android and they all failed with completely different (and very bad) results... Personally, on Android, I would programmatically use a `WebView` and either "print" it to file, or assuming these are truly transient hashs, draw the webview onto a bitmap/canvas and use that in-memory image to assign to your ImageView. You can basically do the same thing on iOS, but you have to jump through more hoops to get the final image in the correct size (I typically use CoreImage filter at the end to crop all the whitespace off the image)

Comment: @SushiHangover I see, maybe I should try a JS rasterizer then, and get the PNG using the JS bridge. Thanks.

Comment: It is clearly due to bug(s) in SkiaSharp's parser/renderer.  It renders fine in my Android library (AndroidSVG): https://imgur.com/a/vCVgTMw

Comment: It looks like some or all of the `transform` attributes aren't being handled properly. [Try getting rid of them.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13329125/1679849)

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Good to know! maybe I should find a native iOS SVG rasterizer a create bindings for both libraries, yours and the one for iOS. Thanks.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I hadn't noticed that until now, thanks for pointing that out. It seems the transformation for the clipping area with brown background isn't being handled properly.