# Inkscape: remove transform from group without ungrouping (keep element IDs)

Tags: svg, inkscape

I have an SVG with grouped elements like so:

```
<g id="group_id" transform="translate(-10,-10)">
  <rect y="50" x="50" height="20" width="20" id="rect_id"/>
  <ellipse cy="70" cx="70" ry="10" rx="10" id="ellipse_id"/>
</g>
```

Using Inkscape I want to get rid of the transform attribute of the group (`<g>`) and **apply** the translation to the subelements (`<rect>` and `<ellipse>`), while keeping them grouped.

The result should in principle look like this:

```
<g id="group_id">
  <rect y="40" x="40" height="20" width="20" id="rect_id"/>
  <ellipse cy="60" cx="60" ry="10" rx="10" id="ellipse_id"/>
</g>
```

[Existing answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44021761/1162143) suggest ungrouping and regrouping (`CTRL-U`, `CTRL-D`), which works fine but *changes the IDs of the elements and the group*.

What I want is the IDs (`group_id`, `rect_id` and `ellipse_id`) of all elements to be kept.

Comment: Open Edit->XML editor (Shift-Ctrl+x), copy transform attribute value from group, delete attribute from group, set transform attribute for each child pasting the value.

Comment: What he said. Or in any text editor really.

Comment: @ccprog Thanks, but I would like the transformations to be **applied** to the sub-elements (made that more obvious in my question). Also I wonder whether there is no simpler solution than manually editing attributes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing transforms in SVG files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329125/removing-transforms-in-svg-files) Going through the answers, tere are realy a lot of good ideas there.