# Recalculate SVG transforms on paths and keep groups

Tags: svg, inkscape

I have a large SVG with several groups. Each group has a transform. I want to recalculate / flatten the transforms while preserving the groups.

```
<g id="a" transform="matrix(2 0 0 2 -69.46 -152.7)">
   <path d="m64.3 645.3h165.9c3...
   <path d="m123 567.4h963...
</g>
<g id="b" transform="matrix(3 0 0 3 -69.46 -152.7)">
   <path d="m64.3 645.3h165.9c3...
   <path d="m123 567.4h963...
</g>
...
```

All the solutions I've found so far involve using Inkscape and then *ungrouping*. I do not want to ungroup them - I have lots of groups and it is important that they stay grouped.

- [SVGcleaner](https://github.com/RazrFalcon/svgcleaner) does not apply transforms to paths within groups.
- [svgo](https://github.com/svg/svgo/issues/624) has an outstanding bug for this
- Inkscape requires ungrouping.

Comment: Have you tried this tool? https://lean-svg.netlify.com/  It can flatten transforms. 
 But it may not work properly on *every* SVG.

Comment: Ah! That does partly work! It flattens the paths. But, sadly, it removes lots of other information like text positioning and hyperlinks. I'll have a play with the settings. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329125/removing-transforms-in-svg-files

Comment: @moini I do not think it is a duplicate. The answers there rely on Inkscape which, as I mention, doesn't meet the needs of this specific question.

Comment: Well, you tagged it Inkscape... And it can do what you need.