# Flatten the transform property in SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, adobe-xd

I have created a vector in adobe XD and then I have exported it as an SVG file. The problem is that in the SVG file in group elements `<g>` there is inline transform property set like this

[image: SVG snippit]

SO when I set an animated class to the element to animate my SVG it does not behave as expected. The animation occurs but the positioning of the element changes probably because the initial `transform: translate` property gets overwritten by new once that I pass via `@keyframes` in external CSS. How do I get around this?

I found a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329125/removing-transforms-in-svg-files) But it's for Inkspsce I currently have access to Adobe Illustrator and Adobe XD only. Plus this answer was not very clear to me as I am not familiar with Inkspace. How do I flatten these `transform: "translate "` property while making sure the elements in SVG remain at their places by updating the `d` property in child elements of  element

My SVG looks something like this before any `@keyframe` animation are applied
[image]

but as soon as I add an animation property to SVG element ( using intersection observer) let say I my code I am applying to element with id `House`, it just shifts from the original position as original transform property mentioned within SVG file gets overwritten by my own translation: transform property that I set in my @keframe animation in CSS

so after the animation, the SVG looks like this :

[image]

**I have used auto-generated animation from [animista](https://animista.net/)**

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE and Edge */
body {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}


#section2 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #333;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

/*second frame animation*/
/*second frame animation*/
/*second frame animation*/
/*second frame animation*/
/*second frame animation*/
/*making opacity of everything 0 before animation begains*/


#House {
  opacity: 0;
}



/*ANIMATION ON HOUSE IS DEFINED HERE GENERRATED DFROM ANIMISTA*/
/*ANIMATION ON HOUSE IS DEFINED HERE GENERRATED DFROM ANIMISTA*/
/*ANIMATION ON HOUSE IS DEFINED HERE GENERRATED DFROM ANIMISTA*/
/*ANIMATION ON HOUSE IS DEFINED HERE GENERRATED DFROM ANIMISTA*/
/*ANIMATION ON HOUSE IS DEFINED HERE GENERRATED DFROM ANIMISTA*/


/*THIS CLKASS BELOW IS ADDED TO ELEMENT WITH ID "House" in html*/

.slide-in-bottom {
  -webkit-animation: slide-in-bottom 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) both;
  animation: slide-in-bottom 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) both;
}

/* ----------------------------------------------
 * Generated by Animista on 2020-6-27 14:35:36
 * Licensed under FreeBSD License.
 * See http://animista.net/license for more info. 
 * w: http://animista.net, t: @cssanimista
 * ---------------------------------------------- */
/**
 * ----------------------------------------
 * animation slide-in-bottom
 * ----------------------------------------
 */
@-webkit-keyframes slide-in-bottom {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(1000px);
    transform: translateY(1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes slide-in-bottom {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(1000px);
    transform: translateY(1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */










  /*CSS DEFINING CLIP PATH AND FILL FOR SVG NOT RELEVANT FOR THIS QUESTION*/
/*CSS DEFINING CLIP PATH AND FILL FOR SVG NOT RELEVANT FOR THIS QUESTION*/
/*CSS DEFINING CLIP PATH AND FILL FOR SVG NOT RELEVANT FOR THIS QUESTION*/


 .cls-1 {
            clip-path: url(#clip-winter_3);
          }
    
          .cls-2 {
            stroke: #707070;
            fill: url(#linear-gradient);
          }
    
          .cls-20, .cls-3 {
            opacity: 0.85;
          }
    
          .cls-3 {
            mix-blend-mode: darken;
            isolation: isolate;
          }
    
          .cls-4 {
            fill: #176d81;
          }
    
          .cls-33, .cls-5, .cls-6, .cls-7, .cls-8 {
            fill: none;
          }
    
          .cls-5, .cls-6, .cls-7, .cls-8 {
            stroke: #fff;
          }
    
          .cls-5 {
            stroke-linecap: round;
          }
    
          .cls-5, .cls-6 {
            stroke-width: 3px;
          }
    
          .cls-7 {
            stroke-width: 2px;
          }
    
          .cls-9 {
            fill: #0d3446;
          }
    
          .cls-10 {
            fill: #71adb5;
          }
    
          .cls-11 {
            fill: #2f2e41;
          }
    
          .cls-12 {
            fill: url(#pattern);
          }
    
          .cls-13 {
            fill: #b6d4d8;
          }
    
          .cls-14 {
            fill: #bcd5d8;
          }
    
          .cls-15, .cls-20, .cls-24 {
            fill: #3f3d56;
          }
    
          .cls-16 {
            fill: #d0cde1;
          }
    
          .cls-17 {
            fill: #ff6584;
          }
    
          .cls-18 {
            fill: #6c63ff;
          }
    
          .cls-19 {
            fill: #575a89;
          }
    
          .cls-21 {
            fill: #e2e2e2;
          }
    
          .cls-22 {
            fill: rgba(49,153,177,0.74);
            opacity: 0.57;
          }
    
          .cls-23 {
            fill: #fff;
          }
    
          .cls-24 {
            opacity: 0.95;
          }
    
          .cls-25, .cls-29 {
            fill: #3b9fb7;
          }
    
          .cls-26 {
            fill: #4eb2c9;
          }
    
          .cls-27 {
            fill: #e6e6e6;
          }
    
          .cls-28 {
            fill: #9f616a;
          }
    
          .cls-29 {
            opacity: 0.1;
          }
    
          .cls-30 {
            fill: #c2848d;
          }
    
          .cls-31 {
            fill: #c1828b;
          }
    
          .cls-32 {
            stroke: none;
          }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Winter</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
  <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
  <section id="section2">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1366 723">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="0.5" x2="0.5" y2="1" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
          <stop offset="0" stop-color="#6bb2d0"/>
          <stop offset="1" stop-color="#c7eafd"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <pattern id="pattern" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1367 471">
          
        <clipPath id="clip-winter_3">
          <rect width="1366" height="723"/>
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
      <g id="winter_3" data-name="winter – 3" class="cls-1">
        <rect class="cls-23" width="1366" height="723"/>
        <g id="SkyBackground" class="cls-2">
          <rect class="cls-32" width="1366" height="768"/>
          <rect class="cls-33" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="1365" height="767"/>
        </g>
        
        <!--PROBLEM PART HERE (HOUSE IN SVG) -->
        <!--PROBLEM PART HERE (HOUSE IN SVG) -->
        <!--PROBLEM PART HERE (HOUSE IN SVG) -->
        <!--PROBLEM PART HERE (HOUSE IN SVG) -->
        <!--PROBLEM PART HERE (HOUSE IN SVG) -->
        <!--PROBLEM PART HERE (HOUSE IN SVG) -->
        <!--PROBLEM PART HERE (HOUSE IN SVG) -->
        
        <g id="House" class="slide-in-bottom" transform="translate(-15 382.031)">
          <rect id="Rectangle_90" data-name="Rectangle 90" class="cls-15" width="16.152" height="55.91" transform="translate(590.714 197.305)"/>
          <path id="Path_906" data-name="Path 906" class="cls-20" d="M780.5,342.294l-40.205-48.333H662.021l-47.834,46.591.967.621h-.345v96.91H780.053v-96.91Z" transform="translate(-162.627 -97.277)"/>
          <path id="Path_907" data-name="Path 907" class="cls-21" d="M956.606,462.961c0,.07-.005.14-.005.211a46.994,46.994,0,0,0,3.424,7.857,19.58,19.58,0,0,0-1,6.283c0,7.363,3.8,13.331,8.484,13.331s8.484-5.969,8.484-13.331a20.178,20.178,0,0,0-.553-4.736,9.688,9.688,0,0,0,1.043-11.8,9.694,9.694,0,1,0,12.564-14.766,9.7,9.7,0,1,0-13.054-9.1c0,.142,0,.283.011.423a9.7,9.7,0,0,0-12.424,7.808,9.7,9.7,0,1,0-6.973,17.817Z" transform="translate(-369.01 -283.968)"/>
          <path id="Path_908" data-name="Path 908" class="cls-22" d="M767.751,293.125l-49.077,57.537v87.207h88.213V339.716Z" transform="translate(-189.461 -97.063)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_91" data-name="Rectangle 91" class="cls-15" width="18.015" height="15.924" transform="translate(564.622 292.58)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_92" data-name="Rectangle 92" class="cls-15" width="18.015" height="15.671" transform="translate(564.622 265.017)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_93" data-name="Rectangle 93" class="cls-23" width="18.015" height="15.924" transform="translate(564.622 292.58)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_94" data-name="Rectangle 94" class="cls-23" width="18.015" height="15.671" transform="translate(564.622 265.017)"/>
          <path id="Path_909" data-name="Path 909" class="cls-15" d="M385.357,225.672,314.1,140.816H174.018L88.41,224.2l1.729,1.112h-.618v173.44H385.26V225.313Z" transform="translate(-27.597 -57.947)"/>
          <path id="Path_910" data-name="Path 910" class="cls-15" d="M528.416,212.954l9.616-7.691c-7.47-.824-10.539,3.25-11.8,6.474-5.836-2.423-12.189.753-12.189.753l19.239,6.984A14.559,14.559,0,0,0,528.416,212.954Z" transform="translate(-257.325 -226.938)"/>
          <path id="Path_911" data-name="Path 911" class="cls-15" d="M760.573,240.5l9.616-7.691c-7.47-.824-10.539,3.25-11.8,6.474-5.836-2.423-12.189.753-12.189.753l19.239,6.984a14.558,14.558,0,0,0-4.87-6.521Z" transform="translate(-316.947 -234.013)"/>
          <path id="Path_912" data-name="Path 912" class="cls-15" d="M705.086,319.327l9.615-7.69c-7.47-.824-10.539,3.25-11.8,6.474-5.836-2.423-12.189.753-12.189.753l19.239,6.984a14.557,14.557,0,0,0-4.87-6.521Z" transform="translate(-302.697 -254.257)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_95" data-name="Rectangle 95" class="cls-15" width="16.152" height="55.91" transform="translate(298.74 74.924)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_96" data-name="Rectangle 96" class="cls-15" width="16.152" height="55.91" transform="translate(462.121 141.395)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_97" data-name="Rectangle 97" class="cls-15" width="16.152" height="55.91" transform="translate(462.121 135.804)"/>
          <path id="Path_913" data-name="Path 913" class="cls-24" d="M603.7,285.367l-55.133-65.482H440.391l-66.105,64.388,1.335.858h-.476V419.059H603.508V285.132Z" transform="translate(-101.016 -78.253)"/>
          <path id="Path_914" data-name="Path 914" class="cls-25" d="M586.506,218.73l-67.822,79.514V418.763H640.592V283.118Z" transform="translate(-138.1 -77.957)"/>
          <path id="Path_915" data-name="Path 915" class="cls-26" d="M363.242,139.32,275.41,242.293V398.369H433.285V222.7Z" transform="translate(-75.622 -57.562)"/>
          <path id="Path_916" data-name="Path 916" class="cls-27" d="M341.806,686.723s.386-8.093,8.3-7.152" transform="translate(-213.09 -348.758)"/>
          <circle id="Ellipse_326" data-name="Ellipse 326" class="cls-18" cx="3.963" cy="3.963" r="3.963" transform="translate(122.516 322.339)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_98" data-name="Rectangle 98" class="cls-27" width="1.119" height="7.83" transform="translate(125.835 332.974)"/>
          <path id="Path_917" data-name="Path 917" class="cls-27" d="M389.452,686.723s.386-8.093,8.3-7.152" transform="translate(-225.326 -348.758)"/>
          <circle id="Ellipse_327" data-name="Ellipse 327" class="cls-18" cx="3.963" cy="3.963" r="3.963" transform="translate(157.926 322.339)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_99" data-name="Rectangle 99" class="cls-27" width="1.119" height="7.83" transform="translate(161.244 332.974)"/>
          <path id="Path_918" data-name="Path 918" class="cls-27" d="M662.789,686.723s.386-8.093,8.3-7.152" transform="translate(-295.525 -348.758)"/>
          <circle id="Ellipse_328" data-name="Ellipse 328" class="cls-18" cx="3.963" cy="3.963" r="3.963" transform="translate(361.065 322.339)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_100" data-name="Rectangle 100" class="cls-27" width="1.119" height="7.83" transform="translate(364.383 332.974)"/>
          <path id="Path_919" data-name="Path 919" class="cls-27" d="M864.24,686.723s.386-8.093,8.3-7.152" transform="translate(-347.261 -348.758)"/>
          <circle id="Ellipse_329" data-name="Ellipse 329" class="cls-18" cx="3.963" cy="3.963" r="3.963" transform="translate(510.78 322.339)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_101" data-name="Rectangle 101" class="cls-27" width="1.119" height="7.83" transform="translate(514.097 332.974)"/>
          <path id="Path_920" data-name="Path 920" class="cls-27" d="M276.606,686.723s.386-8.093,8.3-7.152" transform="translate(-196.345 -348.758)"/>
          <circle id="Ellipse_330" data-name="Ellipse 330" class="cls-18" cx="3.963" cy="3.963" r="3.963" transform="translate(74.061 322.339)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_102" data-name="Rectangle 102" class="cls-27" width="1.119" height="7.83" transform="translate(77.379 332.974)"/>
          <path id="Path_921" data-name="Path 921" class="cls-21" d="M782.806,371.854c0,.081-.006.161-.006.242a53.834,53.834,0,0,0,3.923,9,22.425,22.425,0,0,0-1.146,7.2c0,8.435,4.351,15.272,9.719,15.272s9.719-6.838,9.719-15.272a23.111,23.111,0,0,0-.633-5.425,11.1,11.1,0,0,0,1.2-13.517,11.105,11.105,0,1,0,14.393-16.916,11.108,11.108,0,1,0-14.955-10.422c0,.163.005.324.012.485a11.114,11.114,0,0,0-14.233,8.945,11.107,11.107,0,1,0-7.988,20.41Z" transform="translate(-324.087 -259.233)"/>
          <path id="Path_922" data-name="Path 922" class="cls-21" d="M158.8,234.316l-13.907,19.242L143.546,215.4l-1.663,56.344-12.816-17.732,12.7,21.626-4.206,142.475H150.69l-5.651-160.365Z" transform="translate(-38.038 -77.1)"/>
          <path id="Path_923" data-name="Path 923" class="cls-15" d="M71.612,155.57,53.39,180.781l-1.762-50L49.448,204.6,32.657,181.371,49.3,209.706,43.787,396.379h17.2l-7.4-210.112Z" transform="translate(-13.278 -55.369)"/>
          <path id="Path_926" data-name="Path 926" class="cls-21" d="M558.681,277.421c0,.095-.007.189-.007.284a13,13,0,0,0,3.953,9.347,13.01,13.01,0,0,0,.652,1.218,26.325,26.325,0,0,0-1.345,8.448c0,9.9,5.107,17.926,11.408,17.926s11.408-8.026,11.408-17.926A27.141,27.141,0,0,0,584,290.35a13.027,13.027,0,0,0,1.4-15.866A13.035,13.035,0,1,0,602.3,254.628,13.038,13.038,0,1,0,584.748,242.4c0,.191.006.38.014.569a13.046,13.046,0,0,0-16.706,10.5,13.037,13.037,0,1,0-9.376,23.957Z" transform="translate(-266.135 -233.154)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_103" data-name="Rectangle 103" class="cls-15" width="32.242" height="32.967" transform="translate(220.085 205.167)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_104" data-name="Rectangle 104" class="cls-15" width="32.242" height="32.968" transform="translate(220.085 250.025)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_105" data-name="Rectangle 105" class="cls-23" width="32.242" height="32.967" transform="translate(220.085 205.167)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_106" data-name="Rectangle 106" class="cls-23" width="32.242" height="32.968" transform="translate(220.085 250.025)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_107" data-name="Rectangle 107" class="cls-15" width="32.242" height="32.967" transform="translate(264.676 205.167)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_108" data-name="Rectangle 108" class="cls-15" width="32.242" height="32.968" transform="translate(264.676 250.025)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_109" data-name="Rectangle 109" class="cls-23" width="32.242" height="32.967" transform="translate(264.676 205.167)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_110" data-name="Rectangle 110" class="cls-23" width="32.242" height="32.968" transform="translate(264.676 250.025)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_111" data-name="Rectangle 111" class="cls-15" width="32.242" height="32.967" transform="translate(309.266 205.167)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_112" data-name="Rectangle 112" class="cls-15" width="32.242" height="32.968" transform="translate(309.266 250.025)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_113" data-name="Rectangle 113" class="cls-23" width="32.242" height="32.967" transform="translate(309.266 205.167)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_114" data-name="Rectangle 114" class="cls-23" width="32.242" height="32.968" transform="translate(309.266 250.025)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_115" data-name="Rectangle 115" class="cls-15" width="24.897" height="24.102" transform="translate(412.334 272.061)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_116" data-name="Rectangle 116" class="cls-15" width="24.897" height="24.102" transform="translate(412.334 236.068)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_117" data-name="Rectangle 117" class="cls-23" width="24.897" height="24.102" transform="translate(412.334 272.061)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_118" data-name="Rectangle 118" class="cls-23" width="24.897" height="24.102" transform="translate(412.334 236.068)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_119" data-name="Rectangle 119" class="cls-15" width="24.897" height="24.102" transform="translate(448.75 272.061)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_120" data-name="Rectangle 120" class="cls-15" width="24.897" height="24.102" transform="translate(448.75 236.068)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_121" data-name="Rectangle 121" class="cls-23" width="24.897" height="24.102" transform="translate(448.75 272.061)"/>
          <rect id="Rectangle_122" data-name="Rectangle 122" class="cls-23" width="24.897" height="24.102" transform="translate(448.75 236.068)"/>
        </g>
       

      </g>
    </svg>
    
    
    
    
    
  </section>
  
</body>
</html>
```

The problem causing item in SVG has an id="House" and the animation class is in CSS file at line 179 in style.css with class name `**.slide-in-bottom**`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending a lot of time I have finally found a decent solution to the problem. The problem is with apps of [Adobe](https://adobe.com) and other placed where you download the SVG from like [UNDRAW - free open source svg](https://undraw.co).

They don't take into account that web designers would want to use animation with `transform: translate()` property and put this property within the SVG files you download to save on time and calculating new paths after you group items in SVG (  for example in Adobe XD and Adobe Illustrator). It becomes a nightmare to animate SVG this way.

There are two ways to correct it that I found the easiest and don't require you to use a JS library like SVGO to do this job.

### 1. **Use Figma**

[Figma](https://figma.com) is free to use if you use starter plan which includes 2 editors, cloud storage, good interface better than adobe XD, and several other perks. you can check free plan  [here](https://www.figma.com/pricing-faq/)

**THE FIX**

1. All you need to do is open your SVG in [Figma](https://figma.com) and select Art-board and then find export BUTTON  on the bottom right
2. Select SVG as the export type
3. Then click three dots and check option ***Inclide "id" attribute***
   (adds the name of the layer/ group as an ID in SVG elements recommended)
4. Click on export

   **[DOWNLOAD FIGMA](https://www.figma.com/downloads/)**

[image: Visual representation of steps]

Voila you're done
[Why Figma is far better than adobe Xd](https://www.figma.com/figma-vs-adobe-xd/)

### 2. [Use Affinity designer](https://affinity.serif.com/en-us/designer/)

This requires you to pay about 40$ but it's similar to Adobe Illustrator and has more features as it is not made solely for web UI?UX design.

**THE FIX**

Just open your SVG  -> Export -> SVG -> More -> check  Flatten transforms .

[image]

Comment: I would've never thought to drop the SVG I just exported from Figma back into a blank Figma project and re-export it, but this answer saved my bacon today. So easy. No idea why Figma's initial SVG export (with identical SVG export settings) did not flatten the transforms. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped someone :)