# Recalculate SVG rectangle coordinates removing transform="rotate(-90)"

Tags: svg, transform, inkscape

Following two lines of SVG code produce the same output:

```
<rect x="-172" y="270" width="154" height="137" rx="14" ry="14" transform="rotate(-90)" />
<rect x="270" y="18" width="137" height="154" rx="14" ry="14" />
```

I think, in this particular case (90 degree rotation) a conversion could be performed easily, in theory.

Can InkScape recalculate one into another in this particular case?

Following question [Removing transforms in SVG files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329125) covers automatic removal of `transform="translate()"`, but it doesn't work for `transform="rotate()"`.

Comment: Have you tried using external tools, such as [svgo](https://github.com/svg/svgo)?

Comment: There's no way to further reduce a svg primitive like `<rect>` to non transformed coordinates or attribute values. However, you can convert the rect to a [`<path>` element](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27465/breaking-polygons-into-paths-in-inkscape)

Comment: @herrstrietzel: If I invest enough time in this topic, I could easily write a program for this only purpose, say, in Delphi, but I was wondering if there is something ready for use.