# Applying translate transforms in SVG files from `<image>` or `<use>` elements

Tags: svg, graphics, inkscape

So basically I want to convert this:

transform="translate(...)"

into x/y coordinates. On an `<image>` element

---

**Additional info:**

Similar but more specific than this question:
[Removing transforms in SVG files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329125/removing-transforms-in-svg-files)

My question is specifically about `<image>` elements.

I have an svg element like this:

```
<image width="42" height="55" id="Piz_Buin" xlink:href="assets/svgs/pin.svg"  
    transform="transalte(1.0909,269.65)">
</image>
```

And I want the output to be something like this:

```
<image width="42" height="55" id="Piz_Buin" xlink:href="assets/svgs/pin.svg"  x="1.0909" y="269.65">
</image>
```

So basically I want to convert this:
transform="matrix(1.0909 0 0 1.0909 32.8309 269.65)"
into x/y coordinates. On an  element

How do I achieve this?

Things I have tried but didn't work:

- Use Inkscape to move the  elements around -> exports as transforms
- Use Inkscape "Apply Transforms" plugin -> doesn't support `<image>` elements
- Use Adobe Illustrator to move the  elements around -> exports as transforms
- Use Affinity Designer -> doesn't even support creating `<image>` elements from svgs
- Tried using `<use>` elements instead but same issues as above

I have looked at the svggo github project and it has the convertTransform command, but after reading the API it seems this command is not at all helpful.

Comment: That's not possible in a general case, presumably that's why these tools don't offer that option.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I posted this question in case someone comes up with a soltuion he can post it here for everyone to see it. I guess as of now there is no publicly known way to convert transforms into x/y on `<image>` elements

Comment: because you can't scale or skew with just x/y.

Comment: But is there a way to apply just translate-transforms?

I edited my question to say just that

Comment: Even just translate runs into the problem that if you used a pattern, gradient or clipPath or filter on the element they would all need to be adjusted too.

Comment: But there is the apply transform plugin for inkscape. And it applies transforms for `<path>` elements, it works. But it doesn't work for `<image>` elements. But the problem here would be that you cannot modify the referenced svg, correct? So that narrows this use case down to an svg with `<image>`s with only the transform="translate" property and no other properties that would cause it not to work and that's why noone has written a script yet, since it''s a very specifc use case? Thank you for clarifying!

So: theoretically this is totally possible? But just a narrow use case so noone did it

Answer (score -1):

#### EDIT:

What you could try is simply not moving/scaling anything inside a group. Look here:
https://github.com/svg/svgo/issues/624#issuecomment-1517490815
This will not apply the transform but it will prevent it from appearing in the first place.

---

#### Note: this solution only works for moving `<image>` elements that do not already have x/y properties (which then have default x=0, y=0)

---

After thinking about this, this is a very easy task actually, I was overthinking. You can just do it from within IntelliJ Idea.

In IntelliJ's regex replace, you can follow these steps:

Open the Find and Replace dialog (Ctrl + R or Cmd + R).

Make sure the "Regex" option is enabled (the icon should be blue).

Enter the following regex pattern in the "Find" field:

`transform=translate\(([^,]+),\s*([^)]+)\)`

Enter the following replacement string in the "Replace" field:

`x="$1" y="$2"`

Click "Replace All" or use the other replace options as needed.

The regex pattern captures the X and Y values inside the translate() function using capturing groups `([^,]+)` and `([^)]+)`, which will match any character except a comma and a closing parenthesis, respectively. The replacement string references these captured values using `$1` and `$2` and formats them as x="`<x>`" y="`<y>`".

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Note that the image example is not applied to `<image>` but to path. I just showed it for you to see the visual controls. But it should be done on `<image>` elements.

---

For adding onto x/y from translate (like here https://github.com/svg/svgo/issues/624#issuecomment-265243746) you could probably write a script to do something similar like above. It's probably easier than you might think with the help of ChatGPT. That would be one solution I can come up with.